# Next jsThere was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I got this errors [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lYoq.png) [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWKDJ.png)

This is the code that gives me the error.
I noticed that the error happened when I added the input type password

```
import React from "react";

const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Login with your email</h3>
      <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="password" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the question, I researched Google and found this video showing how to fix this issue. There are a couple of problems that can create this error, **maybe this can help**

This is a known error that many people are receiving every time.

the link to the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAjemAivU24&ab_channel=ByteGrad)

And I copied your code to `codesandbox`
and it works. Please check it yourself [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/test-6glg37?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00073b6nobkh9x4x%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00023b6n17mhjobn%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00043b6n15c2jj0o%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00063b6n6epf05pj%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu5n2z0q00023b6n17mhjobn%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00023b6n17mhjobn%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clu5n2z0q00063b6n6epf05pj%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00053b6ngdrs47a9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00063b6n6epf05pj%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00053b6ngdrs47a9%2522%257D%252C%2522clu5n2z0q00043b6n15c2jj0o%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00033b6npw43qsb1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00043b6n15c2jj0o%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu5n2z0q00033b6npw43qsb1%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).